# monodroid how to put image on image and placing image

Tags: c#, image, parameters, position, xamarin.android

I'm using Monodroid to create an Android application. I'm stuck with a problem, how can I place an image on to another image? Also position parameters (x,y, height, weight) will be taken from a server and I would like to move 2nd image according to those parameters on to 1st image. Is there any chance to find an example code for this issue? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overlay elements by placing them inside a `FrameLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`.

Z-Order is decided by the order in the XML file, so the first element will be behind the second. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/Man" />
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/Frame" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit:
See the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) for information on how to position elements within a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Thank you. Documentation is very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an ImageView in your layout like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/Icon" />
```

This will set the image to be a drawable resource named Icon. You can also set it from C# using the SetImageResource method:

```
var image = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Image);
image.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
```

Depending on where you want to pull the image from there are other methods on ImageView that might help, such as SetImageURI or SetImageDrawable.

Comment: Thanks for help but i think question is not clear enough. I already put image into imageView. what i'm asking is imageView on imageView. For example, there is a face of a man and i would like to put a frame around his face and this frame is my 2nd image. I've been searching for 3 days :(